# Problema de relaciones en Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Tengo unas CATEGORIAS y las categorías tienen un "rubro" que di en llamar ENTRY

```html
Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
      $table->increments('id');
      $table->string('name', 191);
      $table->string('slug', 191)->unique();

      $table->unsignedInteger('entry_id')->default(1);
      $table->foreign('entry_id')->references('id')->on('entries')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');

      $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Cree las relaciones en los modelos correspondientes.

```html
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Category extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug', 'entry_id'];

    public function posts(){
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
    }

    public function entries(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Entry::class);
    }
}
```

y en Entry

```html
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Entry extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'slug'];

    // Vendrian a ser los "Rubros" -> 'POST', 'EVENT', 'COURSE', 'INSTALLATION', 'CLASSIFIEDS'
    public function categories(){
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }

    public function events(){
        return $this->hasMany(Event::class);
    }

    public function courses(){
        return $this->hasMany(Course::class);
    }

    public function installations(){
        return $this->hasMany(Installation::class);
    }

    public function classifieds(){
        return $this->hasMany(Classified::class);
    }
}
```

Ahora bien, cuando quiero mostrar todo en un datatables en el backend, hago lo siguiente:

```html
public function index()
    {
        $categories = Category::all();
        return view('backend-admin.categories.index', compact('categories'));
    }
```

y en el index.blade.php hago

```html
@foreach($categories as $category)
              <tr>
                            <td>{{ $category->id }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $category->name }}</td>
                            <td>{{ $category->entry->name }}</td>
                            <td width="105px">
                                {!! Form::open(['route' => ['categories-admin.destroy', $category->id], 'method' => 'DELETE']) !!}
                                <a href="{{ route('categories-admin.show', $category->id) }}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-eye"></i></a>
                                <a href="{{ route('categories-admin.edit', $category->id) }}" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                                <span><button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></span>
                                {!! Form::close() !!}
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        @endforeach
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

alguien puede explicarme qué estoy haciendo mal ?

Comment: ¿Qué tipo de relación es entre rubros y categorías? ¿uno-a-uno o uno-a-muchos?

Comment: Una categoria puede tener muchos rubros osea: para el rubro "POST" puede haber muchas categorias diferentes

Comment: ¿Eh? según lo que explica en la segunda parte, un rubro puede tener muchas categorías.... pero es lo contrario de lo que dice al comienzo.

Comment: si... despues de poner "añadir comentario" me quede pensando... jajajaja... una categoría pertenece a un rubro y un rubro puede tener muchas categorias...quiere decir que esta bien el titulo de este hilo...

Comment: Entonces es una relación uno-a-muchos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que es una relación uno-a-muchos, y siguiendo con las convenciones de nombres de Laravel, la relación en el modelo Category debería llamarse entry y no entries, según lo explicado en los comentarios, la categoría pertenece a un rubro:

```
public function entry(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Entry::class);
}
```

Adicional a esto sugiero utilizar Eager Loading para cargar la relación antes de pasarla al DataTable, con el fin de evitar el problema de N+1:

```
$categories = Category::with('entry')->get();
```

Más información sobre Eager Loading en la documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: public function entries(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Entry::class);
    }  yo lo tengo definido asi

Comment: No entiendo su comentario.

Comment: ahhhhhhhhhhhhhhh me falto el Category::with('entry')->get();